# Adding new url path in voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

New to Voyager!

I have this page **'/admin/products'** and iam trying to create a new page **'/admin/products/newest'**
which will have permissions to a specific role

So i first added new rows in permissions table (ex : 'browse_newest')

Then i created the related menu in menu builder with dynamic route which is added in web.php :

```
Route::get('admin/products/newest', ['uses' => 'Voyager\ProductsController@newest', 'as' => 'newest']);
```

And last, i added a new function 'newest' in App\Http\Controllers\Voyager\ProductsController

But, after accessing the newest url, i get 404 error

What am I missing her?

Comment: "*i added a new function `newest`*"

So the function that should be called is `newest` but your route is calling the `delivery` function instead

Comment: No iam calling the function newest, I just copy something different. I updated the question